# Rails 3 Override Destroy without Canceling callbacks, and triggering a ROLLBACK

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3, before-filter

My desired behavior is that when destroy is called on an instance, that instance will not actually be destroyed, but it will just be marked as having been destroyed.  This needs to percolate up for any model associations.

In the models that I don't want to actually destroy, but just mark them as deleted I have a `deactivated` field.

From what I can tell the < v3.0.0 way of doing this was to override `destroy_without_callbacks` (That's the way ActsAsParanoid does it), however that method no longer exists in 3.0.0, plus I'm not excited about overriding private methods.

I also tried implementing callbacks, but per the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) any changes made in the call backs are part of the transaction, and are thus rolled-back as well.

My callback looks like:

```
  after_destroy :mark_deactivated

  def mark_deactivated
    if self.respond_to?(:deactivated) then
      self.deactivated = DateTime.now
      self.save
      false
    else
      true
    end
  end
```

How can I prevent the actual destruction of my record without stopping callback, and having my changes rolled-back?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this gem: https://github.com/wireframe/delete_paranoid