# before_destroy callback that halts but also updates model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using a callback to halt a destroy action and instead want to set the :archived_at field. Problem is, the "return false" in my before_destroy causes a rollback that eliminates my update. Solutions to this?

```
class MarkArchived
  def before_destroy(model)
    update_attribute(:archived_at, Time.now) and return false
  end
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_destroy MarkArchived
end

class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_destroy MarkArchived
end
```

Comment: Similar question with a gem-based solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060131/rails-3-override-destroy-without-canceling-callbacks-and-triggering-a-rollback

Comment: I was hoping for a simple solution.

Comment: I know, but I don't think the callbacks support what you want to do, which makes the simple "solution" in this case to not call destroy in the first place, and instead create your own method like `archive`. That's one other option..

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want some your objects (or some classes of objects) to be archived, never destroyed ? I think [this gem](https://github.com/radar/paranoia) might be suited for your use

Comment: Hadn't seen this gem and I'll explore it more, but was hoping for a simple approach that I could approach this problem similarly to what I posed.

Comment: If you manage to find one, please post it here : ) But since callbacks are wrapped in a transaction that is rolled back when one fails (= return false), I don't see how to do that. Maybe overriding the `destroy` method, but it doesn't seem reliable

Comment: You are probably right. I've previously only handled this in controllers, yet that won't stop actions in the console. Came across this approach in an Obie Fernandez presentation and thought it perfect, yet it seems flawed.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
def hide_or_destroy
  if shifts.any?
    update(hidden: true)
  else
    destroy
  end
end
```